# All/Any Implementation in SQL alongside IN

Tags: sql, sql-server, dapper, relational-division

Hello I need to implement few Queries via dapper on a structure similar to below pseudocode.

```
// Tags
[{id: 1, name: "Tech"}, {id: 2, name: "SQL"}, {id: 3, name: "C#"}]

// BlogPost [
{
  Id: 1
  Tags: [1, 2] // Tech, Sql
},
{
   Id: 2,
   Tags: [1,3] // Tech, C#  
},
{
   Id: 3,
   Tags: [1,2,3] // Text, Sql, C#
}]
```

Given this query

```
SELECT 
    [Blogpost].*
From BlogPost blogPost
    LEFT JOIN BlogPostTags tags ON tags.blogId = blogPost.Id
WHERE blogpost.Tags IN (1,2)
```

Running above query i would expect this result.
[{blogId: 1}, {blogId: 2}, {BlogId: 3}]

- I need to obtain a result looking like [{blogId: 1}] given the same parameters (1,2) in above query.
- Also I need to obtain a result like post [{blogId: 1}, {BlogId: 3}] given the parameters (1,2) in above query.

Does sql (MSSQL) have any nifty way to obtain these result?

Or how could I obtain these result in performant manner as I would have more joins in the actual query?

Thanks!

Comment: `LEFT JOIN BlogPostTags tags = tags.blogId = blogPost.Id` do you mean `LEFT JOIN BlogPostTags tags ON tags.blogId = blogPost.Id`? (First equals replaced by `ON`.)

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking here. Some sample data (in DDL and DML) and expected results, will likely help us help you here.

Comment: You want a SQL solution or ORM solution?

Comment: Im looking for a SQL implementation .
Edit. I will try look into the concept of relational division.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "Contains Any" is just a simple `EXISTS` query.

```sql
var tagIds = new[]{ 1, 2, };

using connection = GetConnection();
const string query = @"
SELECT 
    bp.*
FROM BlogPost bp
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM BlogPostTags tags
    WHERE tags.blogId = bp.Id
      AND tags.Id IN @tags
);

var results = await connection.QueryAsync<BlogPost>(query, new { tags, });
```

For the other two requirements, **these are classic [Relational Division](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/t-sql-programming-sql-server/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)**, one being With Remainder, the other being Without Remainder.

For With Remainder, just do an `EXISTS` join, along with a grouped `HAVING` checking that all of them exist.

```sql
var tagIds = new[]{ 1, 2, };

using connection = GetConnection();
const string query = @"
SELECT 
    bp.*
FROM BlogPost bp
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM BlogPostTags tags
    WHERE tags.blogId = bp.Id
      AND tags.Id IN @tags
    HAVING COUNT(*) = @count   -- are all input matched?
);

var results = await connection.QueryAsync<BlogPost>(query, new { tags, count = tags.Length });
```

For Without Remainder, it's similar, but you need to look for *all* tags, and then check in the `HAVING` that the *only* ones that match are the ones you are looking for.

```sql
var tagIds = new[]{ 1, 2, };

using connection = GetConnection();
const string query = @"
SELECT 
    bp.*
FROM BlogPost bp
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM BlogPostTags tags
    WHERE tags.blogId = bp.Id
    HAVING COUNT(*) = @count   -- are all input matched?
       AND COUNT(*) = COUNT(CASE WHEN tags.Id IN @tags THEN 1 END)   -- are all tags in the list
);

var results = await connection.QueryAsync<BlogPost>(query, new { tags, count = tags.Length });
```

Note that Dapper parameterizes lists as `(@p1, @p2)` etc automatically.

---

You can also use a Table Valued Parameter, which is more efficient for large lists.

Define a Table Type, it's best to keep a few useful standard ones around.

```sql
CREATE TYPE dbo.IntList AS TABLE (value int PRIMARY KEY);
```

Then put the values into a `DataTable` and use `.AsTableValuedParameter`.

The query is also slightly different as you would use a join here.

```sql
var tagIds = new[]{ 1, 2, };
var table = new DataTable { Columns = { { "value", typeof(int) } } };
foreach (var tag in tagIds)
    table.Add(tag);

using connection = GetConnection();
const string query = @"
SELECT 
    bp.*
FROM BlogPost bp
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM BlogPostTags tags
    LEFT JOIN @tags input ON input.value = tags.Id
    WHERE tags.blogId = bp.Id
    HAVING COUNT(*) = @count   -- are all input matched?
       AND COUNT(*) = COUNT(input.value)   -- did the join match all tags?
);

var results = await connection.QueryAsync<BlogPost>(query, new { tags = tags.AsTableValuedParameter("dbo.IntList"), count = tags.Length });
```

Comment: Thx alot - I figured there was a concept for this - just wasen't aware of it here.
I will try play around with your examples and see if I can get something going.

Answer (score 1):

These kinds of queries are pretty awkward to express in SQL (note: I'd avoid `LEFT OUTER JOIN` here, as that can cause row duplication)

"contains any" is OK (usually via `EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM BlogPostTags tags WHERE tags.blogId = blogPost.Id AND tags.Tags IN @tags)`, using Dapper's automatic expansion of `@tags`) - however, you are asking for "contains all" and "contains all and nothing else"; these are much more complex; "contains all" would typically be multiple `EXISTS` operations, and "contains all and nothing else" could be that same "contains all" with an additional `NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM BlogPostTags tags WHERE tags.blogId = blogPost.Id AND tags.Tags NOT IN @tags)`

However! I would emphasize again: this operation isn't ideal in SQL. For Stack Overflow post tagging (which looks fundamentally identical to this), we turned this on it's head, by adding a separate index/server that existed *purely to perform tag operations*, including pre-loading all the post/tag data into RAM in optimized ways, and indexing by tag (processing delta updates); this allows a lot of operations to be performed *in memory* using a variety of tricks. Much more effort and work than a simple SQL query, but also much more more efficient.

Comment: Thanks alot - Very good inputs I will look into.

Comment: Standard relational division techniques work fine, not sure why you're so scared of these queries.